# release an object in a block within a block

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Is it actually ok to do the following in blocks. I am not sure whether releasing an object that is outside the scope of the block is fine? In my example below venObject and newPoll are objects outside the scope of the inner block.

```
 [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * objects, NSError * error){
        PFObject * venObject;
        if (!error){
                venObject = [[PFObject alloc] initWithClassName:@"Venue"];
                [venObject setObject:self.venue.identification forKey:@"fid"];
            }

            PFObject * newPoll = [[PFObject alloc] initWithClassName:@"Poll"];

            [newPoll saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * error){
                if (succeeded){
                      [venObject release]; //is this fine?
                      [newPoll release]; //is this fine?
                }
            }];
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should work though I find it cleaner to `autorelease` the objects in the same scope you created them in.

Besides, your code has many bugs. If `error` is non-`nil`, `venObject` will be an uninitialized pointer that can point anywhere. Calling `release` later on that pointer can lead to a crash. And you don't release the objects if the save does not succeed, thereby creating a memory leak.